# Excel VBA how to have Sheet update after Macro

Tags: vba, excel

So I have this code...

```
           'Range("K" & varOffset).Select
            If ActiveCell.Offset(0, -1) = "" Then
                Output = "No"
            Else
                Output = "Yes"
            End If
            ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = Output
```

...But when I use the macro, the cell will only show up "Yes" or "No" regardless of whether I changed the cell to have something in it or not, but I want to be able to update this after I use the macro. Is there any way to put that formula into the cells using VBA?

Comment: I'd like to help, but it is not clear what you want to do. Can you please clarify?

Comment: If you care to chat about the problem, I can be reached in the VBA chat room:  http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/83373/excel-vba

Comment: This code will only ever continue to show `Yes` and `No` as output, because those are the only two values your are assigning to `Output`.

Comment: Afraid I don't have the reputation requirements to use the chat room....but let me try to explain it better. So, the code I have I'm not going to end up using. It was an attempt at a problem, that worked except it was permanent, and not dynamic. What I want is to put the code " =IF(ISBLANK(ActiveCell.Offset(0, -1), "No", "Yes")  " Into the cells, so that when I enter some data, the cell will  update real time.

Comment: Please do not use the [**macros** tag](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/macros/info) for MS Office / VBA.

Answer (score 0):

For a purely VBA solution you need to refer to the `.Value2` property element of the `ActiveCell.Offset(0, -1)` object. Just referencing the object does not do a compare with what value it currently has. Code would be:

```
'Range("K" & varOffset).Select
If ActiveCell.Offset(0, -1).Value2 = "" Then
    Output = "No"
Else
    Output = "Yes"
End If
ActiveCell.Value2 = Output
```

For a solution the creates a formula you would use something like:

```
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=IF(ISBLANK(RC[-1]), ""No"", ""Yes"")"
```

Regards,